# Is it possible to conduct confirmatory factor analysis in SPSS?

Tags: spss, factor-analysis

I found the factor analysis of SPSS seems to only support EFA, but I am not sure. Is it possible to conduct CFA in SPSS?

If not, what statistical tool can be used to conduct CFA? **I especially need CFA with maximum likelihood estimation method**. I found several articles online using Excel to conduct CFA but they solve the parameters by equation group, which does not meet my goal.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to conduct CFA in SPSS. You will need to use some sort of specialized structural equation modeling software. AMOS is often packaged along with SPSS, and can be used for CFA and SEM. Other proprietary options include Mplus, Lisrel, and EQS (and I'm sure a few others). R also has some nice SEM packages available, such as OpenMX, and lavaan (my personal favorite).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by jsakaluk, SPSS can only perform EFA. For CFA, you can use AMOS (co-variance based SEM, SMART PLS(PLS based SEM), PLS_SEM, LISREL, MPlus or EQL. These packages have some advantages and limitations as compared to each other. You can also use R for the same, which can be integrated with SPSS too (23 or higher version).